# max_allowed_packet=1024M... and it still gives me error "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes query..."

Tags: mysql, drupal, caching, error-handling, watchdog

I´ve just moved my Drupal site to a new managed VPS.

Each time I try to run cron, I get this nasty error:

> Warning: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes query:
>   INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link,
>   location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (1, 'php', '%message in
>   %file on line %line.', 'a:4:{s:6:\"%error\";s:12:\"user
>   warning\";s:8:\"%message\";s:1582172:\"Got a packet bigger than
>   'max_allowed_packet' bytes\nquery: UPDATE cache_update SET
>   data =
>   'a:72:{s:10:\"admin_menu\";a:10:{s:5:\"title\";s:19:\"Administration
>   menu\";s:10:\"short_name\";s:10:\"admin_menu\";s:10:\"dc:creator\";s:3:\"sun\";s:11:\"api_version\";s:3:\"6.x\";s:17:\"recommended_major\";s:1:\"1\";s:16:\"supported_majors\";s:3:\"1,3\";s:13:\&qu
>   in /home/drupal/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 135

The thing is that I´ve set  max_allowed_packet to 1024!
And still gives me that error.

That error seems to be related to the admin_menu module, but even after disabling that module, the error is still there (referencing other module) and after disabling that other module, the error is still there, and so on an on.

It seems that the problem is related to the mySQL table "cache_update" but I can´t understand what´s going on. Even after searching Drupal forums, I couldn´t manage to get to the problem. Just found some ways hacking core, wich isn´t good.

I´ve checked that max_allowed_packet syntax is ok in my.cnf file:

```
max_allowed_packet=1024M
```

I think this is a mysql specific issue, so that´s why I´m posting this here.

Thanks for your insight!

Rosamunda

Comment: Did you restart MySQL after setting this value? Also check the value is being reflected in MySQL not by executing the following query on MySQL prompt
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone out there happens to be in the same situation, I´ve solved the error **deactivating the update core module**.

Have found the answer tying a lot of stuff that I´ve read out there, don´t remember where exactly I get the solution. But it works, at leat in my case it did.